# Not able to invoke function defined on $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a directive that implements a multi-step wizard-like functionality.
To that end, I have 3 directives defined, one for the wizard container, one for the actual panels or steps and one for the next/prev controls.

I have an wizard directive that is defined like so:

```
function(angular, plBootstrap, plModalWizardTemplate, plModalWizardPanelTemplate, element) {
'use strict';
plBootstrap.directive('plModalWizard', function() {
    var controller = ['$scope', function($scope) {
        console.log('Controller in the directive: ' + $scope.$id);
        $scope.steps = {};

        // step tracking
        $scope.currentStep = $scope.prevStep = "";

        // Helper methods to add steps to the wizard.
        this.addStep = function(step, nextHandler) {
            //construct object
            $scope.steps[step] = nextHandler;
        };

        // Nav functions
        this.moveForward = function() {
            // should really look up the hash
            // upon being called, this function checks the currentStep
            // then gets the corresponding nextHandler
            // then handles the navigation to the next step
            console.log("Current Step:" + $scope.currentStep);

            var foo = $scope.steps[$scope.currentStep]();
            console.log("Scope in directive:" + $scope.$id)

        }

        this.setAsFirstStep = function(step) {
            this.setCurrentStep(step)
        }

    }];
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: plModalWizardTemplate,
        controller: controller,
        scope: {
            firstStep: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
            ctrl.printHash();
            ctrl.setAsFirstStep(scope.firstStep); // set the first step
        }
    };

});
```

Then, I have the panel/step directive that basically adds the step names and the next-step handlers as key-value pairs into a hash. The idea is that the Wizard will read the `$scope.currentStep` and will execute the corresponding next step handler from the hash.

As you can see from the above code, the `stepForward()` function is invoked when the Next button is clicked on the DOM.

```
<script>
function wizcontroller($scope) {
  console.log("Controller in the page:" + $scope.$id)
  var doStuff = function() {
  console.log("TEST")
}
};
</script>

<div pl-modal-wizard first-step="Jam" ng-controller="wizcontroller">

<div pl-modal-wizard-panel step-id="Jam" goto-next="doStuff()">
    {{stepId}}
</div>

<div pl-modal-wizard-panel step-id="Bread" goto-next='moveForward()'>{{stepId}}</div>
<div pl-modal-wizard-panel step-id="Boo" goto-next="moveForward()">{{stepId}}</div>
<div pl-modal-wizard-panel step-id="Foo" goto-next="moveForward()">{{stepId}}</div>
<div pl-modal-wizard-panel step-id="%steps" goto-next="moveForward()">{{stepId}}</div>
<div pl-modal-wizard-panel step-id="-10" goto-next="moveForward()">{{stepId}}</div>


<!-- Controls -->
<div class="wizard-controls-wrapper pull-right">
    <button type="" pl-sliding-panel-control ng-click="stepBackward()" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</button>
    <button type="" pl-sliding-panel-control ng-click="stepForward()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Here, the "panels" or "steps" have a `step-id` associated with them as well as a `goto-next` attribute that is passed as a reference with `gotoNext: '&'` to the Panel directive.

Here's what the panel directive looks like:

```
// Wizard Panel
    .directive('plModalWizardPanel', function() {
        return {
            require: '^plModalWizard',
            restrict: 'AE',
            transclude: true,
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                stepId: '@',
                gotoNext: '&'
            },
            template: plModalWizardPanelTemplate,

            link: function(scope, element, attributes, plModalWizardCtrl) {
                console.log('Step: ' + scope.$parent.$id);
                // Helper methods from parent directive
                // for getting current step
                scope.currentStep = function() {
                    return plModalWizardCtrl.getCurrentStep();
                }

                scope.setCurrentStep = function(step) {
                    plModalWizardCtrl.setCurrentStep(step);
                }


                // Populate "steps" array of objects with steps.
                yplModalWizardCtrl.addStep(scope.stepId, scope.gotoNext);

            }
        }
    })
```

And the Controls directive:

```
 // Wizard controls
    .directive('plSlidingPanelControl', function() {
        return {
            require: '^plModalWizard',
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: false,
            scope: true,
            transclude: false,

            link: function(scope, element, attributes, plModalWizardCtrl) {

                scope.stepForward = function() {
                    plModalWizardCtrl.moveForward();
                }

                scope.stepBackward = function() {
                    plModalWizardCtrl.moveBackward();
                }

            }
        }
    })
```

The problem arises when I click the **Next** button on the DOM. I expect the `moveForward()` function to run the corresponding next-handler. Instead, it returns `undefined`

I can't pinpoint where my code is going wrong.

Comment: I don't see a declaration of `stepForward()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry about that; added the directive that calls stepForward(). Basically, it is a wrapper around moveForward()

Comment: If you debug/console.log('test') in the `stepForward()` function, does it get called ? Not quite clear from the "returns `undefined`" description.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with writing the `ng-click` on the same element you're putting the directive on. Though transclude might make that possible, haven't had the chance to use transclude myself. I see you have a template `plModalWizardPanelTemplate`, if you try to put the `ng-click="stepForward()"` in there I think it will work. Can you try so we'll be sure?

Comment: I moved the `pl-sliding-panel-controls` directive to the parent container and I still have the issue. All that directive does is give the buttons access to `moveForward()` and `moveBackward()`. As for moving the ng-click to `plModalWizardPanelTemplate`, I don't know if I want the panels themselves to be clickable.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. I think the `ng-click` doesn't find your function because it doesn't reside inside the scope that the directive creates. That's why all I wanted you to try was to write `ng-click="stepForward()"` inside some random div in the `plModalWizardPanelTemplate` HTML so we'll see if that finds the function.

Comment: Oh I see, so `stepForward()` is being called when the **Next** button is clicked. It is this line `var foo = $scope.steps[$scope.currentStep]();` that returns `undefined` This is my hash -  `Object {Jam: function, Bread: function, Boo: function, Foo: function, %steps: function…}`  What I want is for step `Boo` its corresponding function be called.

Comment: I understand now. Does `$scope.steps[$scope.currentStep]` return the function you expect ? (without yet executing)

Comment: Yes it returns a reference to the function - `function (locals) {
                  return parentGet(scope, locals);
                }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69281/discussion-between-omri-aharon-and-frishi).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    function wizcontroller($scope) {
      console.log("Controller in the page:" + $scope.$id)
      var doStuff = function() {
        console.log("TEST")
        return "test"; // <- The function needed to return something. :P
     }
    };
    </script>
```